# SQL join on different versions of table

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database, rdbms

I have multiple suppliers of data, which I will call A, B, & C.  A has a database that is updated monthly.  B & C (my application actually gets more than 2 other data suppliers, and there are over 100) reference a table in A and tell which month from A they are using.  A may update, add or delete records for each monthly release.  Most of the records from A will stay the same.  I currently use multiple databases, and specify the database to use in each join.

What is a good way to store the data from A so that B & C joins to the data will work efficiently?  Does NoSQL or ORDBMS solve this issue?

Comment: Do all your databases reside on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

If ...

- you're using MySQL and
- your user id has appropriate privileges and
- your databases all live on a single server

you can use tables from multiple databases quite easily, just by qualifying the table names in your queries.  For example, this sort of thing performs very well.

```
SELECT a.id, b.vendor
  FROM A.stock a
  JOIN B.shipments b ON a.sku = b.sku
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This was not quite what I was asking as I am already doing this.  

My hope is to find another approach.  Currently I maintain 13 versions of the main database.  This will grow by 1 each month.  Most of these versions only have minor changes (<5%).  The multiple databases (one for each version) may be the best solution, but I am hoping to find a way to handle this in an elegant way that does not require multiple copies.  (Each database is around 2 million records and 200M in size.)